# Selenium: Unable to Select DropDown

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select the month on Gmail signup page using Selenium.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="signup-box">
<form id="createaccount" class="createaccount-form" method="post" action="SignUp?dsh=8533946547080886952&service" name="createaccount">
<input id="timeStmp" type="hidden" value="1437641960669" name="timeStmp"/>
<input id="secTok" type="hidden" value=".AG5fkS9XSKPG0WTmVtKSa4sso_d_jcxGzQ==" name="secTok"/>
<input id="dsh" type="hidden" value="8533946547080886952" name="dsh"/>
<input id="ktl" type="hidden" value="A" name="ktl"/>
<input id="ktf" type="hidden" name="ktf" value="FirstName LastName GmailAddress Passwd PasswdAgain RecoveryEmailAddress "/>
<input id="_utf8" type="hidden" value="☃" name="_utf8"/>
<input id="bgresponse" type="hidden" value="js_disabled" name="bgresponse"/>
<div id="name-form-element" class="form-element multi-field name">
<div id="gmail-address-form-element" class="form-element email-address">
<div id="password-form-element" class="form-element">
<div id="confirm-password-form-element" class="form-element">
<div id="birthday-form-element" class="form-element multi-field birthday">
<fieldset>
<legend>
<label id="month-label" class="month">
<span id="BirthMonth">
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select goog-flat-menu-button-hover" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant=":0" title="">
<input id="HiddenBirthMonth" type="hidden" name="BirthMonth"/>
</span>
</label>
<label id="day-label" class="day">
<label id="year-label" class="year">
</fieldset>
<span id="errormsg_0_BirthMonth" class="errormsg" role="alert"/>
<span id="errormsg_0_BirthDay" class="errormsg" role="alert"/>
<span id="errormsg_0_BirthYear" class="errormsg" role="alert"/>
</div>
<div id="gender-form-element" class="form-element">
<div id="phone-form-element" class="form-element">
<div id="recovery-email-form-element" class="form-element recovery-email">
<div class="form-element">
<div id="country-code-form-element" class="form-element">
<div id="termsofservice-form-element" class="form-element terms-of-service">
<div id="extra-tos" class="form-element"/>
<input id="timeStmp2" type="hidden" value="1437641960669" name="timeStmp2"/>
<input id="secTok2" type="hidden" value=".AG5fkS-iqLwOSgeM3Qqu9w7rAxVOlzyJGw==" name="secTok2"/>
<div class="form-element nextstep-button">
</form>
</div>
<p class="why-information">
</div>
<div class="side-content">
</div>
</div>
<div class="google-footer-bar">
</div>
```

I tried using all of the following but Selenium throws error each time:

Code 1:

```
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup");
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='BirthMonth']/div")));
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText("April");
```

Code 2:

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup");
    Select select = new     Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='BirthMonth']")));     
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText("April");
```

I tried some other variations but none worked. I understand I need to get the "Select" value however when I try obtaining this value using Firebug I don't find any such value in HTML.

I am using Java.

What is correct XPath to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you are trying to use the Select class to manipulate a standard UL element. The Select class will work only for dropdown elements. 
It seems Google is making the list look like a dropdown while it is a regular element. The HTML code certainly does not contain any Select items.

Update:

Try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div")).click();

//Select April
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':4']/div")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click it as follows, where you change the number in the second statement to the month that you're looking for.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":1")).click();
```

if the span isn't clickable you can do this where you get the element by id and grab the div with the onclick event:

```
WebElement monthSelect = driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth"));
monthSelect.findElement(By.xpath("div[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":1")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `Select` only works for html elements with `<select>` tags but you are trying to find `<div>` element.

Furthermore your xpath statement seems to be not correct. You can find the  element with:

```
WebElement divElement = find(By.xpath("//span [@id='BirthMonth']/div"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First click on drop down:

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).click();
```

Then select particular month from the drop down.

for example i want to select April:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[2]/div[@id=':4']/div").click();
```

or

To select April month can alse use this:

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':1']"));
```