# Cant select a dropdown menu (Selenium, java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select from a dropdown menu, but I am getting the following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
```

The following is my code:

```
 Select domainDropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.classname("dijitReset something")));
```

The html element is:

```
<td class="dijitReset something" role="presentation">
    <div class="dijitReset ButtonText" data-dojo-attach-role="presentation">
        <span role="option" aria-selected="true" class="dijitReset TextBoxLabel">internal</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
        <input class="dijitReset dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="value" value="internal" aria-hidden="true">
</td>
```

Comment: As this is custom selet box, this cannot be handled with Select class.You have to automate this case exactly similar like the manual steps,

i.e.,

    Click the element which is intractable.
    Wait for the dropdown appears.
    Click the value from the dropdown.

Comment: Refer this link to get idea. This python example to select react select box. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875653/how-to-use-python-selenium-to-select-values-that-are-hidden-from-react-js-dropdo/52882393#52882393

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: Unable to Select DropDwon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583037/selenium-unable-to-select-dropdwon)